# How to EDIT/REFRESH a property inside IEnumerable<T> in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, ienumerable

My service layer returns `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` to my Controller. `ResortsView` class contains `IList<ProductView>` (ResortProducts). Unique ID for `ResortsView` is SupplierID. Once I loop through `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` and display my results on UI, based on a user action, I would have to REFRESH ResortProducts `(IList<ProductView>)` with UPDATED data from my data store AND I would be using AJAX to make a trip to data store to retrieve UPDATED data. Basically I would like to query `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` by SupplierID and replace ResortProducts for that particular Supplier with data returned by AJAX call.

How can I REPLACE `IList<ProductView> ResortProducts` with another `IList<ProductView>` (which I would get using AJAX) for a particular Supplier (using SupplierID as key) inside `IEnumerable<ResortsView>`?

Here is the code snippet of my objects/classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResortsView : SupplierView
{
    public IList<ProductView> ResortProducts { get; set; }
    public string CheckInTime { get; set; }
    public string CheckOutTime { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ImageView> Images { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SupplierView
{
    public string SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; } 
    public string URL { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProductView
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public ErrorView PricingError { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear and hardly makes sense. Can't see any relevance of the code you have shown and your question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's unclear but I'm guessing you want to update on the web client something that was derived from a list after you call an ajax function. If this is indeed what you are doing then read up on Jquery.

Comment: Darin, Sorry for that. My service layer returns `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` to my controller.`ResortsView` class contains `IList<ProductView>` (ResortProducts). Unique ID for `ResortsView` is SupplierID. Once I loop through `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` and display my results on UI, based on a user action, I would have to REFRESH ResortProducts `(IList<ProductView>)` with UPDATED data from my data store AND I would be using AJAX to retrieve UPDATED data from data store. Basically I would like to query `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` by SupplierID and replace ResortProducts for that particular Supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `IEnumerable<ResortsView>`? that should be easy:

```
foreach(var resort in resorts) {
    resort.ResortProducts = ....
}
```

which should work as a: you have a `set` (which is unusual for a list; I don't recommend it), and b: that shouldn't break the iterator (adding/removing/etc to the underlying list (etc) of resorts would break the iterator).